# backbone.js request where request model is different entity to response model

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js to structure my client side app. Backbone.sync is working nicely for all the CRUD operations, however I'm unclear how to implement one of the server side requests I need to make. This request involves sending a model containing algorithm parameters to the server, and receiving a response containing the results of the algorithm (chart data points, tabular data etc). Calling model.save() doesn't feel like the right thing to do, because backbone is expecting a response containing the updated model, whereas I would ideally like to create an entirely new model with the response.

Should I simply fall back to `jQuery.ajax({data:model.toJson(),...})` and create a new model with the response? Or is there something else clever that I'm missing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do doesn't sound like Create, Update, Read, or Destroy, it sounds more like an RPC call. There's no reason to try to shoehorn a non-CRUD operation into a CRUD system like `Backbone.sync`, you're free to call `$.ajax` yourself whenever it makes sense and an RPC-style call sounds like a good use for doing some manual AJAXing. Presumably you'd convert the `success` results into one or more [`set`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set) calls and let Backbone's event system take it from there.

Comment: Thanks Mu - this was what I was thinking. Just wanted to sanity check myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with the @mu's answer, I want to say that always is a way to encapsulate a *non-CRUD* operation in a *CRUD* one.

For example in your case you can have a Model with loaded *attributes* those are sent to the server as the paramaters needed for *create* the instance.

The server is expecting a *POST* action to create an entity of, let's say, `Chart` Model. The server take the params to build the Chart, and returns the JSON representation of the Chart including both: the initial params and the result params.

Then, in the Backbone layer, the Model will contain all the data you need, not only the result data but also the original data.

Comment: There's always an "it depends" isn't there?

Comment: @muistooshort of course, this is what I wanted: to add another possibility, to use one or the other "depending" on the, always too much complex to explain in SO, context.